# tiny screen on my windows laptop

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 running on my Dell XPS 9550 laptop. For applications, the screen has  tiny buttons and it's hard for me to see the interface and what's going on with the application. Basically, it's hard to work for me. Other applications are running fine and I have tried adjusting the screen resolution but that didn't work.

For example, I am attaching the screenshot of one [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) application which shows everything small :
[image]

Comment: Does it stay that size regardless of what resolution or font size you choose

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have any impact of changing any thing. There are some other applications which behaves in the same manner.

Comment: you use an application which is not DPIaware.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Could you elaborate on DPlaware? I have same issues with Cisco WebEx, Eclipse IDE.

Comment: The program needs to call **SetProcessDPIAwareness** See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464659(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @cup I am looking for a way where I can change the settings some how. The link you have shared has come C# coding in it with which I am not dealing right now. Could you tell me if there are some steps available online which I can follow? Thanks

Comment: the link explains what the developers have to do. request an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround, which has been known to work on other apps which are not DPI aware…

1. Right click the application's Shortcut & select Properties
2. In the Shortcut tab, find the line marked “Target” and add “--noprobe” (without quotes) to the end. For example:

`"C:\Program Files\myApp\myApp.exe" --set InstallLanguage en --noprobe`

3. In the “Compatibility” tab, find and UNCHECK the “Disable display scaling on high DPI settings” option
4. Click “OK” to apply and launch your app as normal.

Comment: When I added `--noprobe` in the target,like the following: `"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe --noprobe"`, I am getting message in separate window : `The name `"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.exe --noprobe"`
specified in the Target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name are 
correct. Am I doing everything correctly?

Comment: close the " before the  --noprobe

Comment: The application  isn't launching after doing that.

Comment: In the “Compatibility” tab, CHECKING  “Disable display scaling on high DPI settings” option worked for me. This option was unchecked for me right from the start. I can at least see bigger stuff on the application window.

Comment: Inspite of doing that, it's not very user friendly.

Comment: It's not really meant to be user-friendly, it's a workaround until the developers get round to making a version that **is** DPIaware.

Comment: The approach I followed was able to enlarge left side of screen, however, right side is still the same, very tiny.